# Is there a way to use : to add a range of values in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have an array and I am trying to sum the values of just a portion of the array.

For example my array is [1,2,3,4,5,6], but I want to add the values only to the third element

[1,2,3]. I thought I used a method involving the semi colon before, but I cant remember for sure.

something like int `sum = Sum (arr[0]:arr[2])` but I am not sure. Does something like this exist?

I think I used it in Python a few years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in method to sum up a subarray. The simplest way could be to stream over the sub-array:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

int sum = Arrays.stream(myArray, 0, 3).sum();
```

where 0 and 3 are the start and end indices (Start inclusive, end exclusive)

Answer (score 5):

Extending [Eritrean's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74585861/1552534) excellent answer you can create an interface with a meaningful name and tuck it away in your library.

```
interface IntRangeSum {
    static public int apply(int[] a, int start, int end) {
         return Arrays.stream(a, start, end).sum();
    }
}


int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int result = IntRangeSum.apply(a, 2, 4);
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use combination [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)) + [`IntStream.limit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#limit(long)):

```
int[] arr = // initializing the array

int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).limit(3).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int[] oldArray ={1,2,3,4,5};
      int[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, 0, 3);
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i: newArray) {
        sum += i;
      }
      System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

**Output:** 6

As far as I know Java doesn't have the slicing notation you know from Python, but this, while more verbose, should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the appropriate variant of [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int)).copyOfRange methods to create and operate on a slice.

Or use a loop:

```
int sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
  sum = sum + i
}
```